# Enable to log the debug statements

Tags: python, logging

Below are 2 different modules: driver module and employee module. I am
trying the log the debug statements in two different files but write now the
log file is getting created with no debug statements in it.

I tried all the way.

## Driver file

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s : % 
(message)s") 
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('driver.log')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

#logging.basicConfig(filename="Employee.log", level=logging.DEBUG, 
format="%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s : %(message)s")

from Employee import Employee 

logger.debug("Before creation of object")
Emp1= Employee("Rahul",1,100000)
logger.debug("After creation of object")
Emp1.display()



#Employee Module
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s : % 
(message)s") 
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("Employee.log")
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

#logging.basicConfig(filename="Employee.log", level=logging.DEBUG, 
format="%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s : %(message)s")
class Employee():
    def __init__(self,name,id,salary):
        self.salary = salary
        self.name=name
        self.id =id
    
    def increment(self, per):
        self.salary=self.salary*((100+per)/100)
    
    def decrement(self, per):
        self.salary=self.salary*((100-per)/100)
    
    def display(self):
        logger.debug("Name is {}".format(self.name))
        logger.debug("ID is {}".format(self.id))
        logger.debug("Sal is {}".format(self.salary))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the level on the logger instance as well. The handlers and the logger each have a level. A logger can have multiple handlers assigned to it, each logging at a different level.

`logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`

Edit: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel